# How to use typescript variables in css files?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, background-image

I am using Angular, my goal is to be able to use a string declared in typescript inside a CSS file. I am trying to set the background image of a navbar component. Later on, the background image path will be received from a database service, that's why I need it to be in the typescript file. I read something about using `[ngStyle]`, but the img will not be updated, I just need the paths to be received from a database. Should I still try to use it? And how? I am a bit lost.

My typescript file has something like:

```
// ...
export class NavbarComponent{

background_url='../../../assets/img/background.png';

  constructor() { }
// ...
```

And in my CSS file i want to do something like:

```
nav{
  background-image: background_url;
}
```

However, this isn't working for me.

How could I better approach this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's not possible to access the ts file variables from the CSS file, but you can get elements from DOM and set style to that from the ts file.

an example:

```
document.getElementById('element').style.backgroundImage = background_url;
```

also if you are using frameworks like angular, you can use @ViewChild to get elements from DOM and style them by using the renderer2 library like this:

```
export class NavbarComponent { 
   @ViewChild('element') element: ElementRef;
   background_url='../../../assets/img/background.png';
   
   constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

   setStyle() {
       this.renderer.setStyle(
           this.element.nativeElement,
           'background-image',
           this.background_url
       );
   }
}
```

and then call the setStyle function where ever you want. 
more from renderer2: https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2